# how to get Count from nested relation in Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

i have these models

```
Category 
 id, category_name   // has many post categories

PostCategory
 id,post_id,category_id   //belongsTo post

Post:  // has many Solutions
id 

Solution:
post_id
```

i don't want to load so many records because i don't need all data like below:

```
$categories = $categories
            ->with(['latest_post',
                'posts' => function ($query) {
                    $query->with([
                    'post' => function ($query) {
                            $query->withCount('solutions');
                        },
                    ]);
                },
            ])
            ->get()
```

i need to get all Category with count of posts that have atleast 1 solution.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: did this not work ? `$categories = $categories->with('latest_post')->withCount('posts.solutions')->get()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$categories = $categories->withCount([
   'posts.post' => function($q) {
      $q->whereHas('solutions')
    }
])
->get();
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.